# How can I adapter error in android studio project

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

```
package com.eterces.bauetattendance;

class ClassAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ClassAdapter.ClassViewHolder> {**
    ArrayList<ClassItem> classItems;
    Context context;

    public ClassAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ClassItem> classItems) {
        this.classItems = classItems;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public static class ClassViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView className;
        TextView subjectName;

        public ClassViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            className = itemView.findViewById(R.id.class_tv);
            subjectName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.class_edit);
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ClassViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.class_item, parent, false);
        return new ClassViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ClassViewHolder holder, int position) {
holder.className.setText(classItems.get(position).getClassName());
holder.subjectName.setText(classItems.get(position).getSubjectName();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return classItems.size();
    }
}
```

Error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference at com.eterces.bauetattendance.ClassAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ClassAdapter.java:47) at com.eterces.bauetattendance.ClassAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ClassAdapter.java:14)
```

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.eterces.bauetattendance.ClassAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ClassAdapter.java:47)
        at com.eterces.bauetattendance.ClassAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ClassAdapter.java:14)

Comment: The question itself should contain the formatted error. Use a comment to indicate the line the error occurs on in the code.

Comment: can you provide code of `class_item.xml`??

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that findviewbyid is not matching with the right one on your xml.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: yes  solve it thanks